# SQL Server and SQL anywhere compatbility

Tags: sql-server, sybase-sql-anywhere

I wish to install a SQL server DB on a VM already running a SQL anywhere DB.

May I encounter a compatibility issue ?

Comment: That's a great question and I do not know. I think the SQL Server and Sybase codebases are so far apart in time and functionality that I'd guess yes. Can you take a snapshot of the VM and experiment with it in its own sandbox?

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason why you should have a problem running SQL Anywhere and SQL Server on the same machine - so long as you have the appropriate resources to meet the needs of both. That will depend entirely on how busy the various databases are. We have many machines running both.

*NB There is no connection between the code bases of SQL Anywhere and SQL Server. SQL Anywhere is a development of WATCOM SQL and although it was owned by Sybase and now SAP, it is an entirely separate product from Sybase (now SAP) ASE - Adaptive Server Enterprise, which did originally have a common origin with MS SQL Server.*

If you run into any problems it might be worth posting on http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/questions/ which is a specialist SQL Anywhere forum.